# How to use values in a raster object to create layers?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster object containing different values in each cell, like in the example below:

```
library(raster)
x <- matrix(1:5,nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
r <- raster(x)
plot(r)

r
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5, 1, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 0.2  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 5  (min, max)
```

[image: Ploted raster with one layer]

I would like to know if there is an easy way to create new layers based on the values of the raster, preserving its spatial structure.

I managed to do that manually in the example below, but I reckon that is not an effective way to do that if you have several values to transform into layers.

```
l1 <- r
l2 <- r
l3 <- r
l4 <- r
l5 <- r

values(l1)[which(values(r)!=1)] <- 0
values(l2)[which(values(r)!=2)] <- 0
values(l3)[which(values(r)!=3)] <- 0
values(l4)[which(values(r)!=4)] <- 0
values(l5)[which(values(r)!=5)] <- 0

r1 <- stack(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5)
plot(r1)

r1
> r1
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 5, 1, 5, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 0.2  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4, layer.5 
min values :       0,       0,       0,       0,       0 
max values :       1,       2,       3,       4,       5
```

[image: Raster with layered values]

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method for that

```
x <- layerize(r)
```

But the layers are `0 / 1` (FALSE/TRUE) as you can see below.

```
x
# (...)
#names      : X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 
#min values :  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 
#max values :  1,  1,  1,  1,  1
```

To get the original numbers back, you could do

```
x <- layerize(r) * unique(r)
```

Or perhaps the more explicit

```
u <- unique(r)
x <- layerize(r, classes=u) * u 

x
# (...)
#names      : X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 
#min values :  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 
#max values :  1,  2,  3,  4,  5
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this in a single line:

```r
r1 <- stack(lapply(unique(r[]), function(i) {r[r[] != i] <- 0; r;}))
```

So that

```
plot(r1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Allan! That is a very elegant solution.

Comment: more elegant and memory safe variation: `stack(lapply(unique(r), function(i) { r[r != i] <- 0; r;} ))`

Comment: @RobertHijmans thanks for that. Could you explain why it has better memory-safety? I have to admit that I don't understand why that would be. I'd appreciate your insight.

Comment: `[ ]` creates a vector with all values in memory. That may fail if you have a very large file or not much free RAM. The raster methods will instead process the file in chunks.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thanks very much - that's great to know.